# How to get items from Hashsets of a List?

Tags: java, jgrapht

I'm using *ConnectivityInspector* to get the connected trees from a graph using the method connectedSets() which give me a List of Hashsets

```
ConnectivityInspector s = new ConnectivityInspector<>(graph);
            System.out.println(s.connectedSets());
```

it would give me all the trees of the forest 
for example 
[ [13, 14], [15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22], [23], [36], [38, 39], [40], [41], [52], [56, 120], [58, 122, 186] ]

My question now that I stuck on it is that how to get the sum of every tree to get then the average of this tree.
for example: s.connectedSets().get(0) = [13, 14].
How can  I add both 13 and 14 and before that make them integer .
I try many ways but I couldn't catch the solution .

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend going into more detail..i.e. code snippets, a more thorough explanation of what you are attempting to do, etc.

Second, from what I am understanding, you have an instance of  [`ConnectivityInspector`](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/alg/ConnectivityInspector.html) and you want to get the sum of every tree, then find the average of the tree. Looking at the documentation, we can see that `connectedSets()` return a type `List<Set<V>>`. Now, I am *assuming* that your `V=int or Integer` You can use a [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) in the nifty Java 8 to sum each set in the list, then store each sum in a List. The value at index i in the list, sums, is the sum of the tree at index i in the connSets. We can then use `sum` again to find the sum of our list of sums, then divide that by the number of  elements in all of the list of sets.

```
public int calculateAverage(List<Set<Integer>> connSets) {

    List<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int elementCount = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < connSets.size(); i++) {
        elementCount += connSets.get(i).size();
        sums.add(i, connSets.get(i).stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum());
    }

    return sums.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()/elementCount;
}
```